# Typescript error TS5055 when importing js file into ts

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, tsconfig, tsc

I want to mix .js and .ts files in the same project, but there is an error (TS5055) that i want to fix, which appears when the project is compiled with tsc, although the output is fine.

here is a tsconfig.json

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2022",
        "module": "ES2022",
        "allowJs": true,
        "lib": [
            "es2022",
            "DOM"
        ],
        "removeComments": true
    },
    "files": [
        "./index.ts"
    ]
}
```

and here is example ts file:

```js
import { lib } from "./lib/impotr.js"

console.log(["imported", lib.hello("friend")]);
```

typescript compiler gives this error:

```
PS D:\WHY> tsc -p .
error TS5055: Cannot write file 'D:/WHY/lib/impotr.js' \
because it would overwrite input file.
```

How to fix it in tsconfig?

[full example img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KyRY.png)

Comment: The error is telling you, your compiling `impotr.js` and TS is then going to compile this to `impotr.js` over writing the original.   You probably want to set an outDir,  eg. `"outDir": "dist"` in compiler options.

Comment: @Keith but that would copy any imported files into outdDir too, is there a way to avoid that ? I'd like to keep relative paths same, i.e: "./index.ts" compiles to "./index.js" and that is enough.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you didn't specify an `outDir`.
Take a look at [this](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-cannot-write-file-because-it-would-overwrite-input-files#:%7E:text=The%20error%20%22Cannot%20write%20file,being%20type%20checked%20and%20compiled.):

```js
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2022",
        "module": "ES2022",
        "allowJs": true,
        "outDir": "build",
        "lib": [
            "es2022",
            "DOM"
        ],
        "removeComments": true
    },
    "files": [
        "./index.ts"
    ]
}
```

If the error is still present after this, it is recommended to set `allowJs` to `false`

Comment: tried that, what if i dont want outdir to be different from base project folder ?

Comment: You want to build the project directly at the root directory? Normally, you would build it inside a separate folder inside the root folder called `build` or `dist` or something along these lines. If you want to build the project regardless in the root directory of the project, I recommend renaming the entryfile into something else than `index`.

You should keep in mind, that building the project creates a bundled file and thus will remove unnecessary/unimported code automatically. The result is non-human readable code

Comment: right, imagine an existing js project and you want to add some typescript into it how would you do it without another outDir ? outDir folder will have duplicate code if i import .js files into .ts. Or that is unimportant, because bundler will get rid of duplicate imports magically, anyway (or not, because file paths will be different)?

Comment: Normally, the bundler will be able to avoid that from happening and will be able to resolve the different paths. Importing components doesn't import the whole JavaScript file. That means, even in case duplicated code would occur, this would only affect the code involved for `lib`. Nevertheless, I cannot say things with certainty since I don't know your codebase

Comment: is there a way to exclude copying **.js** files into **outDir** and keep links in generated .js files (from .ts files) to original imports ?